# Error on Customize- The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying implement userstore but with customization of ApplicationUser but i get error as

"The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context."

What i did till now as

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string AddressCode { get; set; }
}
```

and my dbcontext file looks like

```
public class MYDbContext:IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public MYDbContext()
        : base("DatabaseConnection")
    { 

    }
}
```

And my connection string is like

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DatabaseConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MYUser;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And i have extended UserStore (I am not sure if i did correctly) to override few method as well as use few inbulilt method

```
public class MYUserStore<TUser> : UserStore<ApplicationUser>
{
    private MYDbContext myDbContext;

    public MYUserStore(MYDbContext DbContext)
    {
        this.myDbContext = DbContext;
    }


    public override Task CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        return base.CreateAsync(user); //Here i would like implement on my own way if needed
    }
}
```

And i tried to create repository to inovke MYUserStore and from my controller i invoke UserRepository.

```
public class UserRepository
{
    public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; private set; }

    public UserRepository(UserManager<ApplicationUser> usermanager)
    {
       UserManager = usermanager;
    }

    public UserRepository()
        : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new MYUserStore<ApplicationUser>(new MYDbContext())))
    {

    }


   public async Task<IdentityResult> SaveUser(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        return await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
    }
}
```

Am i doing it correctly? Is it proper way?

Comment: I believe the issue you're facing is that the entity is being preserved across requests but the database context is being re-created so you've got an entity not attached to the context. You shouldn't let entities live longer than the underlying context unless you either manage re-attaching yourself (via `.Attach()` last time I looked in EF4) or better yet by not doing it in the first place and using DTOs - Data Transfer Objects which are similar to your model but only contain the fields you actually need (and possibly some extra info that isn't persisted)

Comment: Actually i used a different model in my controller and from controller i transfered to 'ApplicationUser' model and used 'ApplicaitonUser' everywhere and same way they did MVC project by default. But i did extended few things. Can you direct to any example how to do this?

Comment: Have a read through this article. I'm not certain that it's the problem you're hitting but it's definitely relevant http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2011/03/how-to-update-detached-entity-in-entity.html